# Netbeans: how to add Java EE container to java project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, containers

I am trying to send am email SSL email in Netbeans and I have added both `javaee.jar` and `mail.jar` to my project but I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/MessagingException
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at GUI.CompilerForm.<init>(CompilerForm.java:43)
at Compiler.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

From my research I have found out that I am going to have to run my code inside a Java EE container but I have no experience with this. I have looked this up online with little success, only finding out about Java EE containers.

So how do you add code to a Java EE container and then use this in a project?

Comment: You dont need a JEE container just to send emails from your app. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html for more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *how to add Java EE container to java project*

No, please don't do that. Your sole intent seems to run a Java SE (desktop) application, not a Java EE (web) application. You should not run a Java SE application as a Java EE application.

You should rather find the *right* solution for the concrete problem you're facing instead of asking how to achieve the *wrong* solution.

As to your concrete problem,

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/MessagingException

This basically means that the mentioned class (the `javax/mail/MessagingException`) in the current runtime classpath *only* contains the class and method signatures, but no concrete code at all. In other words, the mentioned class in the current runtime classpath is *empty*. And indeed, the `javaee.jar` which you've there (apparently you downloaded it in a wrong attempt to solve compile/import problems) contains basically the abstract Java EE API *without* any concrete implementation code.

This is not right. **Remove** that `javaee.jar` file altogether. Just the `mail.jar` which you can download from [JavaMail website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) is sufficient. Your concrete problem is caused because the `javaee.jar` file, which *also* contains the `javax.mail` API (but without implementation), got precedence in classloading over `mail.jar` file which contains the concrete `javax.mail` implementation. The `javaee.jar` file should only be used as a compiletime dependency in Java EE projects, not as a runtime dependency of Java SE projects.

Comment: Thanks alot, especially for the clear and well informed answer. I understand it alot more now thanks to you :) cheers :)