# Netbeans: Using JavaMail in normal Java projects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jakarta-mail, netbeans-7

I am creating an desktop application which is capable of sending emails. I downloaded mail.jar and javaee.jar and added it to my project libraries. However, when I am trying to use it, it gives me the error

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - package javax.mail does not exist
```

I imported those packages as,

```
import javax.mail.*
```

It added correctly, as shown in the following image. Please help!! How can I make this work?

[image]

Comment: Did you configured user libraries or how do you use dependencies.

Comment: When you expand `mail.jar` do you see the `javax.mail` package in there? Maybe you have the wrong jar? Btw: you also need `activation.jar` (I don't think you need `javaee.jar` actually)

Comment: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html#InstallJAF
Download JAF and activation.jar is there waiting for you :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163374/netbeans-how-to-add-java-ee-container-to-java-project#comment16278666_12163374

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for the reply. I added that activation file, but still no good. Javax.mail package is inside that mail.jar lib, I expand it and checked that

Comment: @Zaki: Thanks for the reply. I removed that from javaee.jar. Still no good.

Comment: May be this is someting we got to do with netbeans configurations? Please help!

Comment: I have re uploaded the image to show that packages. Please help

Comment: Try cleaning & building your netbeans project. Right click Project -> 'Clean and Build'.

Comment: According to the JavaMail page (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) activation is not required if you are using jdk 6 or better. What Jdk version, java mail version are you using? Also, can you pare your code down to a minimum example that does not compile?

Comment: Thanks everyone!! My special thanks goes to Zaki and a_horse_with_no_name. Thanks a lot! Please provide your comments as answers. I will select zaki's one (the link) and will give up votes for everyone :)